# Find related tags to group of tags

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I am working with a system where users can attach tags to messages for easier searching/identification (just like here on SO). This is the simplified schema:

```
message: message_id
tag: tag_id, tag_name
tag_message: tag_id (FK), message_id (FK)
```

The problem I'm facing is as follows:

*Given an input list of `tag_id`'s I want to find what other tags appear in messages tagged with the inputed tags*

This is the query I came up with:

```
SELECT 
    tag2.tag_name, 
    COUNT(*) AS tagged_message_count

FROM tag AS tag1
    LEFT JOIN tag_message                 ON tag_message.tag_id = tag1.tag_id
    LEFT JOIN message                     ON message.message_id = tag_message.message_id
    LEFT JOIN tag_message AS tag_message2 ON tag_message2.message_id = message.message_id
    LEFT JOIN tag         AS tag2         ON tag_message2.tag_id = tag2.tag_id
WHERE 
    tag1.tag_id = ?
AND 
    tag1.tag_id <> tag2.tag_id
GROUP BY 
    tag2.tag_id;
```

It *works* BUT it works only for 1 tag and I need it to work with groups of tags.

Given tag IDs `1,2,3` we should first find all messages that are tagged with these three tags, then look at what other tags they have and return them.

I have a feeling there will have to be additional joins for each tag, but
I am not sure how to modify the query to acommodate it.

Comment: `...  that are tagged with these three tags, ...` : with **all** these three tags, or with **any** of these three tags?

Comment: all three tags need to be attached to message, we are filtering messages by tags (we only want message that have all these tags, but may have some more)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find messages tagged with 1, 2, *and* 3 using:

```
select tm.message_id
from tag_message tm
where tm.tag_id in (1, 2, 3)
group by tm.message_id
having count(*) = 3;
```

You can find other tags using:

```
select tag_id, count(*)
from tag_message
where message_id in (select tm.message_id
                     from tag_message tm
                     where tm.tag_id in (1, 2, 3)
                     group by tm.message_id
                     having count(*) = 3
                    ) and
      tag_id not in (1, 2, 3)
group by tag_id
order by count(*) desc;
```

If you want messages that have tags 1, 2, *or* 3, then remove the `having` clause.

Comment: Thank you, the second query is what I was looking for. The queries do not compile as is because you forgot the GROUP BY in first query and in the nested query in second example. After these two fixes it works as expected :)

Answer (score 0):

This may *look* overly complex, but it *at least* is an alternative solution ...

---

```
        -- For convience: put the arguments to the query into a CTE
        -- (a temp table *could* be faster for larger sets)
        -- -------------------------------------------
WITH args(tagid) AS (
    VALUES (2), (3) , (4)
    )
        -- messages that have ALL the tags
        -- [the double NOT EXISTS 
        -- is a standard relational-division solution]
, msg_with_all_args AS (
    SELECT msgid FROM msg m
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM tag t
        WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM args a WHERE a.tagid = t.tagid )
        AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT * FROM msg_tag mt
            WHERE mt.msgid = m.msgid
            AND mt.tagid = t.tagid
            )
        )
    )
        -- additional tags, associated with
        -- messages with all tags
, more_tags AS (
    SELECT * FROM tag t
    WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM msg_tag mt
        JOIN msg_with_all_args at ON at.msgid = mt.msgid
        AND mt.tagid = t.tagid
        )
        -- exclude the tags that are already in the set
    AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM args nx where nx.tagid = t.tagid)
    )
SELECT * FROM more_tags
    ;
```